# Integrate php and java application in CAS Server

Tags: java, php, single-sign-on, cas

I have developed three applications. Now i have to integrate three applications under cas server. I have implemented CAS-JASIG server and integrated my java applications with cas server.

My Problem is :

I have to integrate my php application with cas server.
I have a html file in my java application in that html file i have a link for my php application. When i click on that link my php application should be opened.

Guide me where to start. Any Links or tutorials would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Like for you Java application for which you have a Java CAS client: `https://github.com/Jasig/java-cas-client`, a PHP CAS client exists: `https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS` for your PHP application.